# Problem with Database connection in laravel 7

Tags: database, laravel

I am using Laravel 7 and I am also new to Laravel.

I'm trying to create a user Authentication after installing the following :

1. composer require laravel/ui
2. php artisan ui vue --auth
3. php artisan migrate

I tried registering by going http://127.0.0.1:8000/register but anytime I clicked Register it was telling me "that Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = olaoyesunday@yahoo.com)"
 but I changed DB_DATABASE=ecomm3laravel in .env file. 
I wouldn't know the reason why is still seeing Laravel in my DB-DATABASE instead of ecomm3laravel. Please, help me out.

Comment: You need to create the db first before you migrate. For example: `create database laravel`.

Comment: Yes I did and I called it ecomm3laravel, before running composer require laravel/ui

Comment: Try running `php artisan cache:clear` before the migrations

Comment: I did it was saying the same problem. I think it is connection problem because I checked migration table, there are three tables there and it was also in my database that I created but the data from registration page is not entering the database. if it is normal php and MySQL now, I know I will check MySQL_connection, but could it be from my route? or I should recreate the Laravel application

Comment: Thanks vey much. I have rectified the problem the problem was in my web.php I made a mistake in the route functions